# Troube with getting a Single<T> call to work in RxJava and Android

Tags: android

I have a MVVM architecture in my Android app. In an activity, I invoke a method to try to create something from service/repository and return it. I am using RxJava.

Here is the flow:

1. I click something in view, it invokes method in the Activity.
2. Method in Activity invokes method in ViewModel.
3. Method in ViewModel invokes method in Interactor(/use-case).
4. Interactor has access to service and tries to create something from that service.

Here is the code for this:

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreateWalletClick(String password) {
    addWalletViewModel.createWallet(password);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AddWalletViewModel extends BaseViewModel {

private AddWalletInteractor addWalletInteractor;

private final MutableLiveData<Wallet> newWallet = new MutableLiveData<Wallet>();
private final MutableLiveData<ErrorCarrier> newWalletError = new MutableLiveData<ErrorCarrier>();

public LiveData<Wallet> newWallet() {
    return newWallet;
}

public AddWalletViewModel(AddWalletInteractor addWalletInteractor) {
    this.addWalletInteractor = addWalletInteractor;
}

public Single<Wallet> createWallet(String password){
    return addWalletInteractor.addWallet(password)
            .subscribe(wallet -> newWallet.postValue(wallet), this::addErrorToLiveData);
}

private void addErrorToLiveData(Throwable throwable){
    newWalletError.postValue(new ErrorCarrier());
}
```

}

Interactor:

```
public class AddWalletInteractor {

private final KeyStoreServiceInterface keyStoreServiceInterface;

public AddWalletInteractor(KeyStoreServiceInterface keyStoreServiceInterface) {
    this.keyStoreServiceInterface = keyStoreServiceInterface;
}

public Single<Wallet> addWallet(String password){
    return keyStoreServiceInterface.
            createWalletAndReturnWallet(password);
}
```

}

Service:

```
@Override
public Single<Wallet[]> getAllWallets() {
    return Single.fromCallable(()-> {
        Accounts accounts = keyStore.getAccounts();
        int amount = (int) accounts.size();
        Wallet[] wallets = new Wallet[amount];
        for (int i = 0; i<amount; i++){
            org.ethereum.geth.Account gethAccount = accounts.get(i);
            wallets[i] = new Wallet(gethAccount.getAddress().getHex().toLowerCase());
        }
        return wallets;
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

}
```

Problem is I can not manage to get this to work by tweaking the code. Right now it forces me to cast to (Single) in the return of the createWallet() method in the viewmodel. When running the app, it crashes in that method with:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver cannot be cast
>   to io.reactivex.Single
>           at addwallet.AddWalletViewModel.createWallet(AddWalletViewModel.java:31)

Please keep in mind I am new to RxJava, I am still trying to figure it out. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast performed in the `createWallet` method will always fail.

### Solution 1

The simplest way to fix the crash is to change the return type of that method to `io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable`, assuming you're using RxJava 2. If you're using RxJava 1, then have it return `rx.Subscription`. The code you presented that calls the `createWallet` method doesn't seem to use the returned value so it shouldn't make a difference.

### Solution 2

If you really do need the return type to be `Single` and you want to keep the same behavior, then an alternate solution would be to change the `createWallet` method as follows:

```
public Single<Wallet> createWallet(String password) {
    return addWalletInteractor.addWallet(password)
        .doOnSuccess(wallet -> newWallet.postValue(wallet))
        .doOnError(this::addErrorToLiveData);
}
```

The method now returns a new `Single` that does whatever the `Single` returned from `addWallet` does and additionally invokes the appropriate lambda function when a value is successfully emitted or an error occurs. You would also need to modify the call site for the method as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreateWalletClick(String password) {
    addWalletViewModel.createWallet(password).subscribe();
}
```

That `subscribe` call is needed to have the `Single` start emitting values. It takes no parameters because you already do all of the interesting work in the `createWallet` method itself. Both snippets were written with RxJava 2 in mind, but I believe they will also work in RxJava 1 as is.

---

If you haven't already done so, you should check out the [official Rx website](http://reactivex.io/intro.html) as it provides a ton of information on how reactive streams work and how to use them.

Since you're new to RxJava and the documentation is so vast, here's a brief overview of the subscription concept and how it applies to your situation.

RxJava and other stream-based libraries like it have two main components: producers and consumers. Producers supply values and consumers do something with those supplied values.

`Single` is a kind of producer that only produces one value before terminating. In your case, it produces a reference to the newly created wallet. In order to do something with that reference, it needs to be consumed. That's what the `subscribe` method on the `Single` class does. When the `Single` returned by the `addWallet` method produces a value, the lambda passed to the `subscribe` method is invoked and the `wallet` parameter in that lambda is set to the produced value.

The return type of the `subscribe` method is NOT itself a `Single`. When a consumer and a producer are coupled together by the `subscribe` method, it forms a connection which is represented by the `Disposable` class. An instance of that class has methods to cancel the connection before the producer is done producing values or to check if the connection has been cancelled. It is this connection object that is returned by the `subscribe` method.

Note that until this connection is made via one of the `subscribe` overloads, the producer will not start producing items. I.e., a `Single` that is never subscribed to will never do anything. It's analogous to a `Runnable` whose `run` method is never called.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it helped a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help!